# Mostra a data errada

Tags: javascript

Tenho este script:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
<!--    
var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +2;
var dayNr = now.getDate() +1;
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + Day + ", " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year);

document.write('  '+todaysDate);

//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora pretendo mostrar o dia de sexta feira, 1 de junho:

```
var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +3;
var dayNr = now.getDate() +2;
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + Day + ", " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year);

document.write('  '+todaysDate);

//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Mas está a mostrar 32 Maio, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se `dayNr` recebe hoje mais 2 e hoje é dia 30, parece-me óbvio que o resultado será 32, não? Você está trabalhando com inteiros e ele não leva em conta quantos dias tem o mês para voltar a 1 do próximo mês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o código `var dName = now.getDay() +3` e `var dayNr = now.getDate() +2;` você **não** está adicionando dias à data, você está primeiro pegando o número da data atual e então somando um valor à este número, ou seja, você não está adicionando dois dias à data atual, **você está somando o número dois ao número trinta**.

Para adicionar dias você precisa manipular a data e não o valor dos métodos.

Exemplo de como adicionar dias à uma data:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 2); // aqui vem a adição de dois dias
var dName = now.getDay(); // aqui não precisa mais somar, já é sexta-feira
var dayNr = now.getDate(); // aqui já é 01/06/2018
```

...

Adicionalmente, não sei se você já está familiarizado com vetores/arrays, mas não precisaria dos ifs e elses.

```
var meses = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];
nomeDoMes = meses[now.getMonth()];
```

Com o exemplo acima, a variavel `nomeDoMes` terá o valor `"mai"`, e não precisa nem fazer o `"+1"`, porque o vetor também começa do zero.

```js
        var now = new Date();
        now.setDate(now.getDate() + 2); // aqui vem a adição de dois dias
        var dName = now.getDay(); // aqui não precisa mais somar, já é sexta-feira
        var dayNr = now.getDate(); // aqui já é 01/06/2018
        var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
        var yearNr=now.getYear();
        
        if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
        if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
        if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
        if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
        if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
        if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
        if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
        if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
        if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
        if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
        if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
        if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
        if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
        if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
        if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
        if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
        if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
        if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
        if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
        if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
        else {Year = yearNr;}
        var todaysDate =(" " + Day + ", " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year);

        document.write('  '+todaysDate);
```

Comment: Reinaldo, dê uma olhada no seu exemplo, você atribui a variável `data` e depois usa `now`, esse exemplo não vai funcionar embora a intenção esteja correta

Comment: Bem visto, alterei os nomes para os mesmos nomes da pergunta, obrigado.

Comment: mas não funcionou, não aparece a data, nem dia, nem ano e nem o dia por extenso

Comment: acho que faltou você editar alguma coisa para não ter funcionado, coloquei um "snippet" aqui na resposta, clica em executar para ver a data por extenso funcionando. O código é exatamente o que você fez, com as primeiras linhas alteradas.